# Using the TPM to manage disk encryption keys on Ubuntu 20-04?

Tags: encryption, luks, tpm

On a freshly-installed NUC10i7FNK (this year's model), with a cleared TPM2 chip.

I've tried following every Google hit I could find. THe closest I ever got to finding something that matched a current version of the tpm2 tools was using clevis with the tpm2 pin (admittedly, from Redhat), but that fails at the very first step of the recipe:

```
$ sudo clevis luks bind -d /dev/nvme0n1p3 tpm2 '{"pcr_bank":"sha1","pcr_ids":"0,1"}'
ERROR: pcr-input-file filesize does not match pcr set-list
ERROR: Could not build pcr policy
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_createpolicy
```

The man page (such as it is, it's extremely badly written) provides absolutely no help. One would think that if Canonical provides the clevis-tpm2 and tpm2-tools packages, they would have actually tested them and provided some kind of documentation? All I've been able to find from Canonical is some blog entry from 2018, using a very old version of tpm2_tools, with most commands no longer available.

Help?

Comment: https://tpm2-software.github.io/2020/04/13/Disk-Encryption.html use this tutorial. Works well ( in my case store random password on nvram tpm2 chip and use it to unlock luks2 lovume + startup .sh)

Answer (score 4):

The `sha1` bank might be disabled on your tpm2 chip/cpu.
You can use the `tpm2_pcrread` application with no parameters to see which banks are enabled.
If you see the pcr hash list under `sha1` it is enabled, else you may need to choose another bank which does have the pcrs listed.

Chances are you can use the `sha256` bank instead, at which point your command would looks something like the following:

```
sudo clevis luks bind -d /dev/nvme0n1p3 tpm2 '{"pcr_bank":"sha256","pcr_ids":"0,1"}'
```